# merging rows based on a column linux

Tags: linux, awk

I want to add the individual entries from multiple rows based on a column value. 
example input:

```
column 4  column 5    column 7
abc           PD      8
xyz           PD      1
abc           PD      2
xyz           PD      7
xyz           PD      3
```

Expected output:

```
column 4  column 5    column 7
abc           PD      10
xyz           PD      11
```

I tried using squeue command as i'm using to find job user information.subsetting for a specific column where PD is one of the criterion.

```
squeue | tr -s ' ' | awk '($4 == "PD")' | cut -d ' ' -f4,5,7 | awk '{a[$4]+=$7}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}'
```

I am getting 0 as answer.

Comment: post the actual sample, you current input does not contain `PD` string

Comment: I edited the question. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: is there really a space in header columns `column 5` ?

Answer (score 0):

After `cut`, you reduce your `awk` input to only 3 columns, yet keep using `$4` and `$7` fields.

One `awk` program can replace your complete pipeline:

```
$ awk '$5=="PD" {a[$4]+=$7} END{for(i in a) print i,$5,a[i]}' merge 
abc PD 10
xyz PD 11
```

Comment: @KrithikaKrishnan, if this answer helped you, please [consider upvoting it, and/or accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!